# What would be a good way to add a help system to Silverlight applications?

Tags: silverlight

What would be a good way to integrate a help system into Silverlight applications?
The original manual is written in MS Word, so I will need some means to transfer it to whatever format you suggest. Also if your answer is HTML can you explain in details the integration process (HTML popup windows are effectively blocked by most of the browsers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written some code to convert Word documents to XAML to aid in the process:
[Word 2007 XAML Generator](http://www.codeplex.com/Word2007ToXaml)

Michael

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple of solutions that you might find interesting. We're working on a XAML-based help engine for SL as well as a MSWord-plugin that automatically updates your SL projects, adding the converted XAML-based help topics and search database.
See [www.BackSpinSoftware.com](http://www.BackSpinSoftware.com) for more details.